# Tying Autoencoder Weights in a Dense Keras Layer

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am attempting to create a custom, Dense layer in Keras to tie weights in an Autoencoder. I have tried following an example for doing this in convolutional layers [here](https://gist.github.com/dswah/c6b3e4d47d933b057aab32c9c29c4221), but it seemed like some of the steps did not apply for the Dense layer (also, the code is from over two years ago).

By tying weights, I want the decode layer to use the transposed weight matrix of the encode layer. This approach is also taken in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05394.pdf) (page 5). Below is the relevant quote from the article:

> Here, we choose both the encoding and decoding activation function to be sigmoid function and only consider the
>   tied weights case, in which W ′ = W<sup>T</sup>
>   (where W<sup>T</sup>
>   is the
>   transpose of W ) as most existing deep learning methods
>   do.

In the quote above, *W* is the weight matrix in the encode layer and *W'* (equal to the transpose of *W*) is the weight matrix in the decode layer.

I did not change too much in the dense layer. I added a `tied_to` parameter to the constructor, which allows you to pass the layer you want to tie it to. The only other change was to the `build` function, the snippet for this is below:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    assert len(input_shape) >= 2
    input_dim = input_shape[-1]

    if self.tied_to is not None:
        self.kernel = K.transpose(self.tied_to.kernel)
        self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)
    else:
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='kernel',
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
    if self.use_bias:
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    name='bias',
                                    regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.bias_constraint)
    else:
        self.bias = None
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
    self.built = True
```

Below is the `__init__` method, the only change here was the addition of the `tied_to` parameter.

```
def __init__(self, units,
             activation=None,
             use_bias=True,
             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
             bias_initializer='zeros',
             kernel_regularizer=None,
             bias_regularizer=None,
             activity_regularizer=None,
             kernel_constraint=None,
             bias_constraint=None,
             tied_to=None,
             **kwargs):
    if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
        kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)
    super(Dense, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.units = units
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
    self.use_bias = use_bias
    self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
    self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
    self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
    self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
    self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)
    self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
    self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2)
    self.supports_masking = True
    self.tied_to = tied_to
```

The `call` function was not edited, but it is below for reference.

```
def call(self, inputs):
    output = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
    if self.use_bias:
        output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')
    if self.activation is not None:
        output = self.activation(output)
    return output
```

Above, I added a conditional to check if the `tied_to` parameter was set, and if so, set the layer's kernel to the transpose of the `tied_to` layer's kernel.

Below is the code used to instantiate the model. It is done using Keras's sequential API and `DenseTied` is my custom layer.

```
# encoder
#
encoded1 = Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")

decoded1 = DenseTied(4, activation="sigmoid", tied_to=encoded1)

# autoencoder
#
autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(encoded1)
autoencoder.add(decoded1)
```

After training the model, below is the model summary and weights.

```
autoencoder.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 10        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_tied_7 (DenseTied)     (None, 4)                 12        
=================================================================
Total params: 22
Trainable params: 14
Non-trainable params: 8
________________________________________________________________

autoencoder.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
array([[-2.122982  ,  0.43029135],
       [-2.1772149 ,  0.16689162],
       [-1.0465667 ,  0.9828905 ],
       [-0.6830663 ,  0.0512633 ]], dtype=float32)


autoencoder.layers[-1].get_weights()[1]
array([[-0.6521988 , -0.7131109 ,  0.14814234,  0.26533198],
       [ 0.04387903, -0.22077179,  0.517225  , -0.21583867]],
      dtype=float32)
```

As you can see, the weights reported by `autoencoder.get_weights()` do not seem to be tied.

So after showing my approach, my question is, is this a valid way to tie weights in a Dense Keras layer? I was able to run the code, and it is currently training. It seems that the loss function is decreasing reasonably as well. My fear is that this will only set them equal when the model is build, but not actually tie them. My hope is that the backend `transpose` function is tying them through references under the hood, but I am sure that I am missing something.

Comment: By "tie" do you mean there are two Dense layers with exactly the same weights? If that's the case then why don't you use a single Dense layer and apply it in different parts of your model?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the question to show what I mean by "tying" the weights. Unfortunately, it is not as simple as using the same layer since the weight matrix has to be transposed.

Comment: I can't test it, but I am quite confident that your approach is correct (although I am not sure whether `self._trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)` is strictly necessary, since the weights `self.tied_to.kernel` are in theory already trainable). I would suggest you to check the weights after training, and make sure that they are the same. You could also visualize the computational graph with Tensorboard.

Comment: @JamesMchugh I think you should not use `self._trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)` at all since these weights are not trainable from the viewpoint of custom Dense layer. Either remove that line entirely, or use  `self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)` instead so that you can access the weights from the custom Dense layer independently (i.e. using `get_weights()` method).

Comment: How do you invoke your custom layers to build a model?

Comment: @MikhailBerlinkov Sorry, I added the relevant code snippet.

Comment: @rvinas The reason I added `self._trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)` is the `get_weights` method checks the `trainable_weights` and `non_trainable_weights` properties in the model. At least, that is what it looked like after reviewing the `Layer` class in the `keras.engine.baselayer` module. Before adding this, the `get_weights` method did not return the weights in the DenseTied layer's kernel. When I use `get_weights` for the tied layers, the weights do not seem to be tied, but maybe it is possible that the weights in `_trainable_weights` is not updating properly but the kernel is.

Comment: @today So in this case, the encode layer would be indirectly responsible for learning the weights the decode layer needs as well? I thought it would be trainable so weights of the decode layer (which would be tied to the encode layer), would be updated directly when backpropagation occurs on that layer. At least, that is what the algorithm in the article looked like it was saying. I will try appending them to `self._non_trainable_weights` then.

Comment: For anyone interested, the problem was that by using `k.variable(k.transpose(self.kernel))`, I broke the tie. I had to use `k.transpose(self.kernel)` instead. However, this does cause some problems when trying to use `autoencoder.load_weights(file)` since `self.kernel` is a tensor and does not have the `assign` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So after showing my approach, my question is, is this a valid way to tie weights in a Dense Keras layer?

Yes, it's valid.

> My fear is that this will only set them equal when the model is build, but not actually tie them. My hope is that the backend transpose function is tying them through references under the hood, but I am sure that I am missing something.

It actually ties them in a computation graph, you can check in printing `model.summary()` that there's just one copy of these trainable weights. Also, after training your model you can check weights of corresponding layers with `model.get_weights()`. When the model is build there're no weights yet actually, just placeholders for them.

```
random.seed(1)

class DenseTied(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units,
                 activation=None,
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 tied_to=None,
                 **kwargs):
        self.tied_to = tied_to
        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)
        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2)
        self.supports_masking = True

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) >= 2
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]

        if self.tied_to is not None:
            self.kernel = K.transpose(self.tied_to.kernel)
            self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)
        else:
            self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
                                          initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                          name='kernel',
                                          regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                          constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                                        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                        name='bias',
                                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                        constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        else:
            self.bias = None

        self.built = True

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) >= 2
        assert input_shape[-1] == self.units
        output_shape = list(input_shape)
        output_shape[-1] = self.units
        return tuple(output_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        output = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        if self.use_bias:
            output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')
        if self.activation is not None:
            output = self.activation(output)
        return output


# input_ = Input(shape=(16,), dtype=np.float32)
# encoder
#
encoded1 = Dense(4, activation="sigmoid", input_shape=(4,), use_bias=True)
decoded1 = DenseTied(4, activation="sigmoid", tied_to=encoded1, use_bias=False)

# autoencoder
#
autoencoder = Sequential()
# autoencoder.add(input_)
autoencoder.add(encoded1)
autoencoder.add(decoded1)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")

print(autoencoder.summary())

autoencoder.fit(x=np.random.rand(100, 4), y=np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(100, 4)))

print(autoencoder.layers[0].get_weights()[0])
print(autoencoder.layers[1].get_weights()[0])
```

Comment: I did use `model.get_weights()` after training the model, but the weights did not seem to be properly tied. The weights of the decoder did not seem to be the transpose of the decoder. I have not tried `model.summary()` yet, but that is a good call. I will update you when I test this. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I used `model.get_weights()` and `model.summary()`, but it did not seem like there were any indications that the weights were tied.

Comment: Could you try removing `self._trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)`? These are not trainable weights of this layer but of the other. I think what happens is that they get updated in two places of the graph and that's why they are different.

Comment: I did change it to `self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.kernel)`, but the weights still seem to be different. If the kernel is not added to either of these lists, it will not print when using `model.get_weights()`.

Comment: Could you show your `model.get_weights()`  and `model.summary()` when you add to non-trainable weights. Also, could you share the `call` method?

Comment: The weights and model summary have been added. I also added the `call` method, but it was not edited.

Comment: I added `__init__` as well. I assumed that the difference in  the number of parameters is caused by the biases, which we do not want to tie in this case. I might have missed something here though.

Comment: If `call` method is the same, then you should have `input_shape = output_shape` as you apply `transpose` to kernel. I reproduced your example (with this fix) and have the same weights after training.

Comment: Are you saying I should add `input_shape = output_shape` to the beginning of the `build` method?

Comment: No, but passing `units` to your constructor doesn't make much sense. Could you show what you run, e.g. in colab notebook so that you end up with different weights?

Comment: As an output, I get  32/100 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6486
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6482
[[-0.76939976  0.43526956 -0.15488403  0.6467319 ]
 [ 0.38243875 -0.44671533 -0.8416126  -0.05631071]
 [ 0.523417   -0.08810697 -0.61158824 -0.7192199 ]
 [-0.26845294  0.37578496  0.00717913  0.05403641]]
[[-0.76939976  0.38243875  0.523417   -0.26845294]
 [ 0.43526956 -0.44671533 -0.08810697  0.37578496]
 [-0.15488403 -0.8416126  -0.61158824  0.00717913]
 [ 0.6467319  -0.05631071 -0.7192199   0.05403641]]

Comment: I found the problem thanks to your code. It was because I was converting the output of `transpose` to a `variable`. I guess this was untying the weights. I got an error when writing the class, and I thought it was because `kernel` was not a `variable`. I guess I was wrong about that. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was trying to set the encoding_dim smaller than the dimension of data. With this code, I was getting error if the encoding_dim was set less than 4. Removing `assert input_shape[-1] == self.units` line in `compute_output_shape()` fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Mikhail Berlinkov, 
One imporant remark: This code runs under Keras, but not in eager mode in TF2.0. It runs, but it trains badly.

The critical point is, how the object stores the transposed weight. 
self.kernel = K.transpose(self.tied_to.kernel)

In non eager mode this creates a graph the right way. In eager mode this fails, probably because the value of a transposed variable is stored at build (== the first call), and then used at subsequent calls.

However: the solution is to store the variable unaltered at build, 
and put the transpose operation into the call method.

I spent several days to figure this out, and I am happy if this helps anyone.